# How to access values inside a multiple array JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How can I access array data inside my json object `data`?

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const getData = () => {
      axiosInstance
        .get(url + slug)
        .then(result => setData(result.data))
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      getData()
    }, [])
```

Here are something I've tried:

```
  console.log(data['symbol'])
  console.log(data[0]['symbol'])
  console.log(data[0].symbol)
```

Here is the data being used in my state:
[image]

To keep it simple, lets say I want to the access first array, and console log all values for `symbol`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: console.log(data[0][0]). It will print first object inside first array of data.

Comment: I've tried that but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Where are you logging it? If you have it outside the fetch, `data` is empty on the first render, so will throw an error. Also, you should either add `getData` to your `useEffect` dependency array, or move it inside.

Comment: It's outside the fetch, I'm just playing with my JSON object and getting a feel for it because I eventually will map this data.

Comment: Then check if it has been populated before trying to access it. `if (data.length){console.log(...);}`

Comment: That maybe because data is still empty. getData is have finish yet. To prevent it from throwing error, you can put console.log(data[0][0]) inside i```if``` block. ```if(data[0]) { console.log(data[0][0]) }```

Comment: Thank you for the help :) Now I understand given both of your examples. Pilchard btw, when I added `getData` to the dependency array, my console was caught in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `data` looks like an array of arrays of objects.

This should work:

```js
data[0][0].symbol
```

To log all the symbols of the first array:

```js
console.log(data[0].map(item => item.symbol))
```

Comment: From pilchard comment, I understand that if this is outside of the fetch then I will get an error. Not quite sure why because I can access the `data` through console log just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To access the first array you can use this `data[0]`    to map through all the objects inside the first array and log them you do the following

```
data[0].map(item => console.log(item.symbol))
```